# What database software can easily export variables to a book & website?

Tags: database, programming, books

For a project in History and Political Science, I am collecting tons of electoral data, including Names of each, Votes cast to each, Turnout, Rejected Ballots... they've never been digitized yet.

The data spans: - at least 70 years of elections - more than 600 constituencies, evolving over time - various voting methods were in use

First of all, are all major DB types or softwares able to include this? Which ones? I am fully new to this.

Second, I intend to produce 1) a website 2) a book.

What good database system could automatically complete of both my book and my website data pages? OpenOffice Database? Microsoft Access? MySQL? Anything I ignore? thanks.

Comment: 1) **No** database system will *automatically complete both my book and my website*. You need intermediate data structures and programs to output those, *filled with your data*. You may have a small advantage there when you use an software package like OpenOffice or MS Office, because then the integration could be easier.

Comment: 2) **Any** modern database can handle the amount of data you specify. What is vitally important is that you study *database normaization* so that you build a properly normalized database (at least 3rd form) in whatever DBMS you use.

Comment: Given my previous remarks I'm voting to close your question as 'too broad'. You are in the stage 'how do I tackle this project' and 'what kind of software should I use' which does not exactly make your question a software recommendation that people can give meaningful answers too. Almost any DBMS answered here will do.

Comment: Any database can do this. To make your question less broad, please ask "what software?" instead of "what database?". Also, please describe what the resulting website should look like: Read-only view of the data? Collaboration features? Also, do the website&book need to show graphs/statistics, or just the raw data?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) data frames for this.

- Free
- Handles huge data sets
- You can manipulate your data to produce the views that you are looking for.
- You can output as web page(s) easily by using iPython which mixing data, tables, formulas, code, etc.
- The ipython can be saved as HTML, HTML presentation slides, LaTeX, PDF, ReStructuredText, Markdown, etc.

Comment: If I might add to this: For the website, you could use pythons [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) web framework. It is powerful, has a database interface (Postgresql, MySQL, MondoDB, you name it) and you can use pandas in your views etc. [Here](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/) you should find out whether django is a candidate for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a web-site later, make this a criteria, even at the initial phase when you are scanning documents.

MySql seems like a good way to go. Well established, stable, free, tons of support, books & examples, easy to use and integrated very well into PHP.